# What is the correct pronunciation of 垃圾?

Tags: mandarin, pronunciation

The word `垃圾` is sometimes pronounced `laji`, but other times I've seen it pronounced as `lese`, which pronunciation is deemed to be more correct? Are they both interchangeable?

Comment: Where are you that you have heard `lese`?

Comment: The standard pronunciation in Taiwan is le4se4.

Comment: For example on source--Google Translate: [https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%E5%9E%83%E5%9C%BE%E6%A1%B6]; pinyin are given as `lese`, but the pronunciation they give is `laji`. Also, this deck of cards through Anki has the same feature/bug [https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/767493033].

Comment: I came here for an answer because I was reading a website that was teaching Chinese grammar, and they were changing the Pinyin for 垃圾 from lājī to lèsè without any explanation.

Answer (score 12):

*(As I very recently learned)*

#### The standard pronunciation for `垃圾` is lājī in the PRC and lèsè in Taiwan

An obvious question to ask is **Why?** Although I could not find an authoritative source, I have seen a number of claims that are very similar to each other. I'll refer to [the talk page for 垃圾 on Wikipedia](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:%E5%9E%83%E5%9C%BE):

> 标准普通话是读laji，以前的国语是读lese，因为垃圾本来是在方言中首先使用的，所以现在南方各地的方言里还是保留着当时的发音，后来普通话吸收了这个词，但是读音根据形声字的一般发音规则作了改变，所以读音改为laji，而台湾依然保留了lese的读音。--3dball 21:01 2006年1月13日 (UTC)
>
> 垃圾一词在宋朝就有, 见吴自牧的梦梁录. 本为lese, 是共产党有边读边念错变成laji --Bobbybuilder 2010年12月6日 (一) 18:36 (UTC)

An translation I've taken a few liberties with:

> **A**: The reason that [on the mainland] it is read `laji` but [in Taiwan] it is read as `lese` is that the word was originally from a dialect. The word was borrowed into Mandarin, but the standard pronunciation eventually become `laji` based on a (mis)interpretation of the characters' phonetic components.
>
> **B**: The characters *do* show up in Song dynasty texts (e.g., ...), but it was the CCP who mispronounced it.

Other important evidence:

- [The wiktionary page](http://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%9E%83%E5%9C%BE) shows pronunciations in many dialects. If the characters are cognate, it's always an "s" for the second one.
- The characters don't show up in Song dynasty `广韵` book of pronunciations (e.g., probably new characters), although they do show up in other Song dynasty texts.
- The word was written with different characters in different texts; the standard was established rather late.
- `laji` did not show up as the dictionary standard until PRC times.
- In Cantonese, it's `laap6 saap3`
- In Shanghainese: `[lɒ²²ɕi⁴⁴]`, Suzhou dialect: `[lɒ³¹⁻²²si⁴⁴]`

Comment: I changed the part of your quote that's in traditional script into simplified; it looked really strange having both scripts in the same paragraph. The phonetics for the Shanghainese phrase doesn't sound quite right. Maybe it's an obsolete/dated pronunciation.

Comment: It'll be better to reference the [wiktionary](http://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%9E%83%E5%9C%BE) page rather than a wiki talk page. There it's suggested that the 垃圾 written form does date back to Song times, although not in dictionaries. Based on this I'm inclined to believe that the `laji` pronunciation dates back further than PRC.

Comment: @CongXu I'm not suggesting the characters `垃圾` didn't exist until the PRC; I'm suggesting that the pronunciation `laji` didn't exist until around then. (Certainly the narrative I'm seeing is "Northerners who didn't have `垃圾` in their native dialect mispronounced it based on the phonetics"). If you have more sources that can help date when the `laji` pronunciation became common/popular _please help find some and edit them in_.

Comment: Pete, I did some diggging around and found that lehseh is the dated pronunciation in Shanghainese. You'd be hardpressed to find anyone pronouncing it like this in Shanghai nowadays. The majority would pronounce it as '/lɑ̈ɕi/' (falling-rising-falling).

Comment: @deutschZuid Interesting. That's pretty similar to the 苏州话 pronunciation given by Wiktionary: [lɒ³¹⁻²²si⁴⁴]. If you can find a link, please edit in the pronunciation ^_^

Comment: 苏州话 usually sounds more 'feminine' and 'graceful'. So the shift from an open central vowel to a back vowel is a common feature, so is the change from an alveolo-palatal sibilant to a alveolar sibilant. You can actually find the info about the Shanghainese pronunciations on Cong Xu's wiktionary page.

Comment: @deutschZuid Oops. Somehow I didn't see it there (I was looking at the translations at the bottom). The si->xi transition is indeed quite common (Mandarin did it after all); not sure the "femininity" of Suzhou dialect has much influence on sound change though.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete haha.. 'femininity' is a subjective term. Maybe I am influenced by 苏州评弹, whose male performers usually have very feminine voices.

Comment: The reason for considering the CCP mispronounces `垃圾` is not convincing enough. 1) as you listed, some dialects like Cantonese pronounce 垃 `laap6`, so making it `lā` is reasonable. 2) though 垃 isn't present in 康熙字典, 圾 is in and having a meaning `(a rare character, sounds bìng)同岌`([as an interchangeable character,] the same as 岌). So, making 圾 pronounce jī seems reasonable too. In conclusion, I doubt if it can be described as "mispronunciation".

Comment: @Stan It _is_ entirely reasonable to look at the character 圾 and say "I think that's probably pronounced jī". The point is that the _word_ for garbage was originally pronounced lèsè, so lājī is a mispronunciation.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete Mm, I'm always thinking that the character limit in the comment makes me difficult to express all of my ideas :P I was to come up with a supposition: `垃(soil) + 圾(岌, 《說文》山高貌, like a hill) = 垃圾(garbage)`. Because I can't find materials to prove it, I'm not sure if I'm correct. But it's a reasonably possible origin.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete 土坷垃(tǔ kē lā) is Henan dialect, it means little soil blocks. Soil is often considered dirty, so 垃 is really a good image for "dirty things". In my supposition, 垃圾(lājī) would construct a lively metaphor for garbage -- in this aspect, considering "垃圾" just as an unbreakable morpheme is not so elegant.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete **I find this wonderful paper [“垃圾”考](http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/SrcShow.asp?Src_ID=1098).** Conclusion: 1) my guess is wrong. 2) the mispronunciation for 圾 has a long history.